# Stand-alone novel with clones, re-populating Earth, lunar base and apocalypse, probably hard SF

Tags: story-identification, novel

I have a question regarding 1 book I have read but can't re-read as I don't remember its author and title. I can't find it using Google and some databases. I don't think I'll ask for another books so I'm not registered. Sorry if it's against the rules here.
Also - I'm Polish and have read that book translated and it's possible its original and Polish titles are very different so finding its author could be helpful. Sorry for all the potential mistakes, my English is average.

What I remember:
It's similar to Baxter's *Evolution* in some aspects, that it includes a super volcano that explodes and destroys whole continents and all humans on the surface plus animals and plants. It covers thousands of years while *Evolution* more like millions and leads to a kind of machine intelligence - but in my missing book there's only organic intelligence.

What else, some people travel to a lunar base when the volcano explodes and it's maybe 10 or less individuals. One leaves behind his wife and unborn child and later develops depression and PTSD as he couldn't save them and tries to kill himself or kills himself. Turns out the remaining people must clone themselves as they get old and sick (radiation or effects of poisons and gases they inhaled in the last moments on the planet, or something similar). Many generations of clones live and die in that base and some go to Earth and try to re-populate it and bring some samples of animals and plants stored in magazines of their base but every attempt can't succeed as the planet is in bad condition. Then the base becomes dangerous as they no longer have spare parts and metals they need to make spare parts and last clones must go back. Only then they see a planet with animals and plants evolved from original animals we know. Turns out one of previous generations of clones spread life on the planet but their communicators got destroyed and they couldn't notify their fellow clones on the moon. Some children of the clones on the surface survived and had children who evolved and created another population of neo-Earthlings and they had some legends about "gods" living in heaven and inside the moon that one day will return to their children that is people on the surface.

It's possible I remember multiple books glued together. It wasn't a part of a series but a stand-alone book or it was a part of a series but only 1 part available in my country.

Comment: Hi there! That's a very solid story-id question, perhaps the only thing we can ask is when did you read it/when would it have been published? :)

Comment: It doesn't match all of your parameters, but CJ Cherryh's _[40,000 in Gehenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forty_Thousand_in_Gehenna)_ covers centuries of development on a planet (not Earth) after a large number of clones were sent to colonize it. And Neal Stephenson's _[Seveneves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seveneves)_ has people cloning themselves to survive after Earth surface us ravaged by bits of the destroyed Moon falling on it.

Comment: I think I read it more than 5 years ago (that was when I moved and the specific library I had the book from is no longer the nearest local library I frequent). It could be: published 6-7-ish years ago. I don't think it was older from the Golden Age, ideas and science wasn't that old.

Comment: I will check Stephenson but one can't live in a lunar base safely when Moon no longer exists. A temporary base in a larger remaining piece could be possible??? Definitely not Gehenna. I know the plot, I have every book in Alliance-Union series available in my country.

Comment: @migotka Some pieces remained that were big enough to land on.

Answer (score 1):

*Terraforming Earth* by Jack Williamson looks like it has some similar elements.

> When a giant meteor crashes into the earth and destroys all life, the
>   small group of human survivors manage to leave the barren planet and
>   establish a new home on the moon. From Tycho Base, men and woman are
>   able to observe the devastated planet and wait for a time when return
>   will become possible.
>
> Generations pass. Cloned children have had children of their own, and
>   their eyes are raised toward the giant planet in the sky which long
>   ago was the cradle of humanity. Finally, after millennia of waiting,
>   the descendants of the original refugees travel back to a planet
>   they've never known, to try and rebuild a civilization of which
>   they've never been a part.
>
> The fate of the earth lies in the success of their return, but after
>   so much time, the question is not whether they can rebuild an old
>   destroyed home, but whether they can learn to inhabit an alien new
>   world--Earth.

A [sfsignal.com review](https://www.sfsignal.com/archives/2004/05/review_terraforming_earth_by_jack_williamson/) describes its "Agents of the Moon" section as:

> yet another generation of clones survey a still-older Earth to find
>   that a previous (and briefly mentioned) generation’s expedition was
>   successful in setting up a new society. Interestingly, the society is
>   made up of believers (the Regents) and doubters (the Scienteers).

Comment: Terraforming Earth isn't my book. The end is different and I checked every source I know of, it looks like there wasn't a Polish translation of this book. Many by the same author but not this particular. At the moment I have a theory. Many years ago I read another book (that is the book I'm looking for) or somehow got Terraforming Earth in English, remembered some parts of it and mixed them with details from another book - and remember the conglomerate of 2 or more books as my missing book. Anyway I'm grateful for all suggestions and I think it closes my investigation. Thanks!